# how can I catch 'resource not found' exception and redirect url instead of showing an error?

Tags: php, zend-framework, redirect, exception

I have a website that is served on Apache 2.2 and Zend Framework 1.11.5 with php 5.3.

whenever a user tries to enter a page that doesn't exists he gets an exception "resource not found". how can i catch that exception and redirect the user to a different domain on the same path instead of showing an error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your `ErrorController::errorAction()` to detect/redirect on those not-found exceptions.